# Parse: Include nested pointers in query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following structure in my app:

```
MessageRecipients -> Message -> User 
                     Message -> Activity
```

where the -> represent a pointer. I have separated out the messages and message recipients tables because I need to capture whether the message has been read by each recipient.

The query I want to do is find all of the messages for a recipient. So I need to include the message in the MessageRecipients query but I would also like to include the nested User and Activity objects.

```
var MessageRecipient = new Parse.Query('MessageRecipient');
messageQuery.equalTo('recipient', query.recipient);
messageQuery.include('message');
```

The message comes back without the activity and sender populated. I tried calling messageQuery.include('activity') but that didn't work as activity is not on the correct table.

Is there a way to do this query or do you have to do separate queries for the nested objects?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll need to include those sub-sub-objects as well:

```
messageQuery.include('message');
messageQuery.include('message.user');  // if user is the column name
messageQuery.include('message.activity'); // if activity is the column name
```

Comment: Just a useful hint for anyone reading this answer - even though you can include sub objects using dot notation like this correct answer describes doesn't mean that's how you access to the object in your adapter.  You will have to break up access like this: ParseObject activity = object.getParseObject("message").getParseObject("activity"); if you try ParseObject activity = object.getParseObject("message.activity"); if will give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: Lets say that i make a query to the `MessageRecipients` and i want this query to have ascending order from the class `Activity` (createdAt), is there any way to make this happen ?

Comment: Nope, you can only order based on columns in the base class for the query.  Sounds like you'll have to do some sorting on the client side.

Comment: @MaxWorg thanks a lot! I think that should be included at the end of the answer. Ran into the same issue on Android :)

Comment: Hint for includeAll() in JS. It is not working with includeAll() as far as I tried but if you include like in example it works

Answer (score 19):

You can also achieve this in one line:

```
messageQuery.include( ["message", "message.user", "message.activity"] );
```

Comment: great point! details like this are never alluded to the Parse docs!