# Parse include key in sub query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have two columns one is from user and other is to user. now i am checking if current user is in from user or to user. i am querying like the following.

```
var matQueryFrom = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("VRMatches"));
var matQueryTo = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("VRMatches"));
matQueryFrom.equalTo("FROM_USER_OBJECTID",user.id);
matQueryFrom.include("TO_USER");
matQueryTo.equalTo("TO_USER_OBJECTID", user.id);
matQueryTo.include("FROM_USER");
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(matQueryFrom, matQueryTo);
```

i want to get from user if the current user matched to user. OR i want to get to user if the current user matches from user. How can i achieve that or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: i used following link and included both touser and fromuser in my main query for now. but i am still wondering how this will be achieved.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515784/parse-include-nested-pointers-in-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the Parse documentation becuase it clearly says:

> Note that we **do not**, however, support GeoPoint or non-filtering
>   constraints (e.g. near, withinGeoBox, limit, skip,
>   ascending/descending, **include**) in the subqueries of the compound
>   query.

You might be able to add both of the include constraints to the final compound query. Maybe this will work but obviously you will not be able to distinguish which sub query returned which row as the results of both sub queries were `Or`ed together:

```
var matQueryFrom = new Parse.Query("VRMatches");
var matQueryTo = new Parse.Query("VRMatches");
matQueryFrom.equalTo("FROM_USER_OBJECTID",user.id);
matQueryTo.equalTo("TO_USER_OBJECTID", user.id);
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(matQueryFrom, matQueryTo);
mainQuery.include("TO_USER");
mainQuery.include("FROM_USER");
```

Comment: i already did include in main query as i commented on my question. Thanks for your reply. That portion of documentation was missed from me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, my main point was to let you know about `include` not being supported in sub-queries. Does it work now ?

Comment: Yes i added to main query.