# How to get parent and their childs entry from parse server?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using parse open source. I have three tables:
1. ForumPost
2. ForumReply
3. ForumComment

When a user creates a post it will store into ForumPost, when someone adds a reply to the post we are storing post reply on ForumReply table. Now any user can comment on Forum Reply we are storing comments into ForumComment.

**What I want:** I have an post id, Now I want to get all reply of that post along with their respective comments.

**What I have done** I am able to get Post Reply but not able to get their comments in the same query.  I am calling a Cloud function for every post reply to get comments.

Here is my current code

````
    isRequestLegitimate(request).then(function(result) {
        if (result.legitimateRequest) {
            var forumQuery = new Parse.Query("ForumPost");
            var userPointer = new Parse.User();
            userPointer.id = result.activeUserId;
            forumQuery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.postId);
            forumQuery.include("offer");
            forumQuery.include("offer.artist");
            forumQuery.include("creator");
            forumQuery.include("replies");
            forumQuery.include("replies.comments");
            forumQuery.include("replies.creator");
            forumQuery.select("objectId","offer", "offer.isActive","offer.stopDate", "offer.objectId", "offer.artist.firstname", "offer.artist.lastname",
                "offer.title", "offer.picHash", "title", "text", "offer.offer", "creator", "creator.firstname",
                "creator.lastname", "replies", "replies.objectId", "replies.text", "replies.creator.firstname", "replies.creator.lastname",
                "replies.isRead", "replies.comments.isRead");
            forumQuery.first({
                useMasterKey: true
            }).then(function(forumPost) {
                if (forumPost == null) {
                    response.success("0"); //not found
                } else {
                    response.success(forumPost);
                }
            }, function(error) {
                response.error(error);
            });
        } else {
            response.error("You must be logged in!");
        }
    });
});```

Could someone please let me know how I can fetch comments?
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse: Include nested pointers in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515784/parse-include-nested-pointers-in-query)

Comment: @duxfox, I do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: you have `.select('replies.comments.isRead')` what happens if you change that to simply: `replies.comments`? do you then get the comment objects?

Comment: @ArthurCinader I have added `replies.comments.title`, `replies.comments.description` and I'm able to access them.  But the issue is I am not able to access pointer detail. replies.comments also have some pointer like `creator`, `to`

Comment: Have you tried to add `forumQuery.include("replies.comments.creator");` and `forumQuery.include("replies.comments.to");`?

Comment: When I added each field in `forumQuery.select`  it is working. Thanks, guys for your prompt messages.